# Why can't Terraform SSH into my EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to ssh into a newly created EC2 instance with terraform. My host is Windows 10 and I have no problems SSHing into the instance using Bitvise SSH Client from my host but Terraform can't seem to SSH in to create a directory on the instance:

My `main.tf`:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "instance" { 
  name = "inlets-server-instance" 
  description = "Security group for the inlets server" 
  ingress { 
    from_port = 22 
    to_port = 22 
    protocol = "tcp" 
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] 
  } 

  egress { 
    from_port = 0 
    to_port = 0 
    protocol = "-1" 
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] 
  } 
}

resource "aws_instance" "tunnel" {
  ami = "ami-07b4f3c02c7f83d59"
  instance_type = "t2.nano"
  key_name = "${var.key_name}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.instance.id]

  tags = {
    Name = "inlets-server"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${aws_instance.tunnel.public_ip} > ${var.public_ip_path}"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "mkdir /home/${var.ssh_user}/ansible",
    ]

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      host        = "${file("${var.public_ip_path}")}"
      user        = "${var.ssh_user}"
      private_key = "${file("${var.private_key_path}")}"
      timeout     = "1m"
      agent       = false
    }
  }
}
```

My `variables.tf`:

```
variable "key_name" {
  description = "Name of the SSH key pair generated in Amazon EC2."
  default     = "aws_ssh_key"
}

variable "public_ip_path" {
  description = "Path to the file that contains the instance's public IP address"
  default     = "ip_address.txt"
}

variable "private_key_path" {
  description = "Path to the private SSH key, used to access the instance."
  default     = "aws_ssh_key.pem"
}

variable "ssh_user" {
  description = "SSH user name to connect to your instance."
  default     = "ubuntu"
}
```

All I get are attempted connections:

```
aws_instance.tunnel (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
aws_instance.tunnel (remote-exec):   Host: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
aws_instance.tunnel (remote-exec):   User: ubuntu
aws_instance.tunnel (remote-exec):   Password: false
aws_instance.tunnel (remote-exec):   Private key: true
aws_instance.tunnel (remote-exec):   Certificate: false
aws_instance.tunnel (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: false
aws_instance.tunnel (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false
```

and it finally timeouts with:

```
Error: timeout - last error: dial tcp: lookup XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
: no such host
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Show the Security Group resource.

Comment: It wouldn't let me post it in the original question because it said I had too much code. Here it is: `resource "aws_security_group" "instance" {
  name = "inlets-server-instance"
  description = "Security group for the inlets server"
  
  ingress {
      from_port = 22
      to_port = 22
      protocol = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}`

Comment: due to these problems, I use local-exec for ssh

Answer (score 0):

You didn't talk about your network structure.

Is your win10 machine inside the VPC? If not, do you have internet gateway, routing table, NAT gateway properly set up?

It would be cleaner and safer to create an Elastic IP resource to access the IP address of your machine with terraform knowledge instead of trying to get it from the machine. Surely, the local exec will be quicker than the remote exec but you create an implicit dependency that might generate problems.